# Progress output with Distribution.TestSuite.QuickCheck

Tags: haskell, testing, quickcheck

I am using `Distribution.TestSuite.QuickCheck` to run QuickCheck tests via `cabal test`. My test module exports a single definition:

```
module MOS6502.Tests.Main (tests) where

import Distribution.TestSuite.QuickCheck as QC

import MOS6502.Tests
import MOS6502.Tests.Framework

tests :: IO [QC.Test]
tests = return [ testProperty (testLabel test) (runTest test) | test <- allTests ]
```

Whenever I have a failing test, I get the output that I'd expect anyway, e.g.

```
Running 1 test suites...
Test suite tests: RUNNING...
Test case BEQ: Fail "(after 91 tests): Branch correctly taken"
Test case BNE: Pass
Test case BVS: Fail "(after 75 tests): Branch correctly taken"
Test case JMP abs: Fail "(after 1 test): PC"
Test case JMP ind: Fail "(after 1 test): PC"
Test case STA zp: Pass
Test case STA zp,X: Pass
Test case STA abs: Pass
Test case STA abs,X: Pass
Test case STA abs,Y: Pass
Test case STA (zp,X): Pass
Test case STA (zp),Y: Pass
Test suite tests: FAIL
Test suite logged to: dist/test/mos6502-kansas-lava-0.0.0.0-tests.log
0 of 1 test suites (8 of 12 test cases) passed.
```

However, while the tests are running, I am getting no output (and I also only get minimal output at the end when all tests pass).

Is there a way to have `cabal test` print out these `Test case Foo` messages to give me an idea of the progress?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
cabal test --show-details=always
```

(See the [Cabal User Guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/installing-packages.html) for more information)

Comment: Nope. That only causes the `Pass` messages to appear even for fully-passing runs. But the messages are still only printed after the whole process finishes.

Comment: Interestingly, the linked Cabal doc mentions `--show-details=streaming` but that is neither real-time nor does it show passes...